# ObservableCollection с выборкой

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть у меня в ВМ `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`. Все замечательно, когда коллекция пополняется, вьюха сразу отображает изменения. Но вот потребовалось мне в отдельном месте отображать не всю коллекцию, а с выборкой (типа где `TheMyClass.Prop == someValue`). Ну и само собой это ответвление от основной коллекции так же должно реагировать на поступление новых элементов. Как это грамотнее осуществить? Просто мне на ум пришло несколько способов и ни один не нравится.

Например, подписаться на изменение основной коллекции, создать отдельную коллекцию, в которую добавлять только те элементы, которые соответствуют условию.

Еще вариант, создать просто свойство с выборкой через `Where()`, и обновлять это свойство каждый раз, когда происходит изменение основной коллекции.

А какие у вас есть варианты?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`CollectionViewSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) с фильтром :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Filtered"
                          Source="{Binding Items}"
                          Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Filtered}}"></ListBox>
```

`Items` - это `ObservableCollection<TheMyClass>` из ВМ, `CollectionViewSource_Filter` - обработчик события с логикой фильтрации:

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (TheMyClass)e.Item;

    // Если выставить в false, элемент пропадет из фильтрованной коллекции.
    // По умолчанию true.
    if (item.Prop != someValue)
        e.Accepted = false;
}
```